# How to covert json object to json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The JSON object I have

```
{Yana: 1, Pirelli: 2, Good Year: 1}
```

Expected results

```
series: [
         {name: 'Yana', data: [1]},
         {name: 'Pirelli', data: [5]},
         {name: 'Good year', data: [5]}
        ]
```

Comment: that's just an (invalid) Object, and you want an Array of Objects - there is no JSON

Comment: edited..that was sample data

Comment: edited comment .. it's still nothing to do with JSON ... it's just an **invalid** Object ... if it were JSON ... it'd be a **string** that looks like `{"Yana": 1, "Pirelli": 2, "Good Year": 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object.entries will help here

```js
var input = {"Yana": 1, "Pirelli": 2, "Good Year": 1};
var output = Object.entries(input).map(([name, v]) => ({name, data:[v]}));
console.log (output);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
const object = {"Yana": 1, "Pirelli": 2, "Good Year": 1};

Object.keys(object).map(key => {
    return {name: key, data: [object[key]]};
})
```

`Object.keys` gets an array of the key names from `object` which can be iterated over using `map`. Using this it's then simple to construct the output array in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach()` in `Object.keys()` for `data` object:

```js
var data = {"Yana":1,"Pirelli":2,"Good Year":1};
var res = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => res.push({name: key, data:[data[key]]}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you provided is not a valid JSON object. In JSON format your object would be:

```
{"Yana": 1, "Pirelli": 2, "Good Year": 1}
```

Assuming that you have that in a string, first thing you need to do is to parse it as JS object:

```
const jsonData = '{"Yana": 1, "Pirelli": 2, "Good Year": 1}'
const object = JSON.parse(jsonData);

// Now get all the keys from the object:
const brands = Object.keys(object);

// Finally, create a new object with the desired properties:
const result = brands.map(brand => {
  return {
    name: brand,
    data: object[brand]
  };
})
```